How do I implement a password that users can change in another window in Java Swing
The program I'm designing allows users to change an admin password ONLY AFTER entering the current admin password into a password field in the class setupModeLock below. However, the password never saves to the setupModeLock variable pWord
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class setupModeLock {
    private static int pWord;
    public final JFrame miniScreen;
    setupModeLock() {
        miniScreen = new JFrame("Setup Mode");
        final JLabel info = new JLabel("Please enter an admin password");
        final JPasswordField adminField = new JPasswordField();
        final JLabel result = new JLabel("");
        info.setBounds(120, 300, 200, 30);
        adminField.setBounds(120, 325, 200, 30);
        result.setBounds(200, 325, 400, 30);
        miniScreen.add(info);
        miniScreen.add(adminField);
        miniScreen.add(result);
        adminField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent code) {
                String password = new String(adminField.getPassword());
                try {
                    int val = Integer.parseInt(password);
                    if(val == pWord) 
                    {       
                        miniScreen.dispose();
                        new setUpMode()
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        adminField.setText("");
                        result.setText("Incorrect Password");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    adminField.setText("");
                    result.setText("Invalid Password");
                }
            }
        });
        miniScreen.setSize(780,700);
        miniScreen.setVisible(true);
        miniScreen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static void changePassword(int newPass)
    {
        pWord = newPass;
    }
    public static int getPword()
    {
        return pWord;
    }
}

The next class actually displays the button that changes the password
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class setUpMode extends setupModeLock{
    public JFrame window;
    setUpMode() {
        super();
        miniScreen.dispose();
        window = new JFrame();
        window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        JButton modPassword = new JButton("Change Admin Password");
        modPassword.setBounds(1000, 800, 300, 30);
        window.add(modPassword);
        modPassword.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent c) {
                new PasswordChanger();
            } 
        });
    }
}

In the class PasswordChanger, the user enters the password to the PasswordField, and then uses the inherited method changePassword to change the password in setUpModeLock
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class PasswordChanger extends setupModeLock implements ActionListener {
    JPasswordField thisField;
    JLabel success;
    Container container;
    CardLayout cardlayout;

    PasswordChanger() {
        super();
        miniScreen.dispose();
        JFrame newPlace = new JFrame("Change Password");
        container = newPlace.getContentPane();
        cardlayout = new CardLayout();
        container.setLayout(cardlayout);
        success = new JLabel("");
        thisField = new JPasswordField();
        thisField.addActionListener(this);
        container.add("a", thisField);
        container.add("b", success);
        newPlace.setSize(300,100);
        newPlace.setVisible(true);
        newPlace.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        newPlace.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent bro) {
        val = new String(thisField.getPassword());
        try
        {
            int pCode = Integer.parseInt(val);
            changePassword(pCode);
            success.setText("Password successfuly save. Exit now");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            success.setText("Faulty Password type. Exit and try again");
        }
        cardlayout.next(container);
    }
}

But after running it, not even the Change Password JButton appears in setupMode.
I tried inheriting over multiple classes, but my password always remains at 0. What can I do to modify the password in setUpModeLock so that any call to changePassword() will make the new password a constant in all subclasses.

Sorry, but I think that you are confused as to what inheritance is for or why or when to use it. None of these classes should be inheriting from setupModeLock. Instead, if you want a GUI window to share data with another, then they both need to refer to the same object and not inherit from the same class. Also as a side note, any modal window should be a JDialog, not a JFrame.

When posting here, strip your code down to a bare minimum.

How are you calling this code?

You can work with a lot less lines of code if you leverage already existing methods from e.g. JOptionPane. Here is an example where some bits still need to be filled in. It defines a panel with the necessary input elements and getters to read the data. Then there is a method changePassword() that shows the panel to the user and evaluates the data.
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.TextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ChangePassword extends JPanel {
    
    private JTextField username;
    private JPasswordField oldPassword;
    private JPasswordField newPassword1;
    private JPasswordField newPassword2;
    
    public ChangePassword() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        Insets insets = new Insets(3,3,3,3);
        add(new JLabel("Username"), new GridBagConstraints(0,0, 1, 1, 0,0, GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, insets, 0,0));
        username = new JTextField(30);
        add(username, new GridBagConstraints(1,0, 1, 1, 0,0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, insets, 0,0));
        add(new JLabel("Old Password"), new GridBagConstraints(0,1, 1, 1, 0,0, GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, insets, 0,0));
        oldPassword = new JPasswordField();
        add(oldPassword, new GridBagConstraints(1,1, 1, 1, 0,0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, insets, 0,0));
        add(new JLabel("New Password"), new GridBagConstraints(0,2, 1, 1, 0,0, GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, insets, 0,0));
        newPassword1 = new JPasswordField();
        add(newPassword1, new GridBagConstraints(1,2, 1, 1, 0,0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, insets, 0,0));
        add(new JLabel("Repeat Password"), new GridBagConstraints(0,3, 1, 1, 0,0, GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, insets, 0,0));
        newPassword2 = new JPasswordField();
        add(newPassword2, new GridBagConstraints(1,3, 1, 1, 0,0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, insets, 0,0));
    }

    
    public String getUsername() {
        return username.getText();
    }
    
    public char[] getOldPassword() {
        return oldPassword.getPassword();
    }
    
    public char[] getNewPassword1() {
        return newPassword1.getPassword();
    }
    
    public char[] getNewPassword2() {
        return newPassword2.getPassword();
    }
    
    public static void changePassword() {
        ChangePassword cp = new ChangePassword();
        if (JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
                null, cp, "Change Password...", 
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, 
                null, null, null) == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            // check if username and old password are correct
            String username = cp.getUsername();
            char[] oldPassword = cp.getOldPassword();
            
            // check if newPassword1 and newPassword2 are the same
            char[] newPassword1 = cp.getNewPassword1();
            char[] newPassword2 = cp.getNewPassword2();
            
            // change password
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password changed");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cancelled by user");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        changePassword();
    }
}

